# How to get extent of drawn rectangle feature in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, angular

My code:

```
var geometryFunction, maxPoints;

    const value = 'Circle';

    geometryFunction = createBox();

    const source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});

    const vector = new VectorLayer({

      source: source,

    });

    this.drawing = new Draw({

      source: source,

      type: value,

      geometryFunction: geometryFunction

    });

    // this.windowZoom = true;

    this.map.addInteraction(this.drawing);
```

By I can draw the box, but I am trying zoom to that box.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extend of your Vector Layer from the source by something like:

```
let extent = source.getExtent();
```

Another way would be to get the extend of your feature by:

```
let extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
```

Then you could zoom to that extent by using Views [fit](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit) function:

```
map.getView().fit(extent);
```